# How to transfer ERC1155 data(Ownership) mapping from one smart contract to another?

Tags: nft, mapping, solidity-0.8.x

I am developing an NFT Marketplace where I am distributing free NFTs(out of 3 defined categories, Diamond,Gold,Silver). I have developed a dropsite smart contract for this distribution. The dropsite module will only be executed once like it will mint only 1000 NFTs then it will be closed.

After distribution, I want those NFTs to be usable on Marketplace contract. For this I want to send the ownerships of Distributed NFTs from Dropsite contract to Marketplace contract. SO that the user may send/transfer/sell those NFTs on marketplace.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my Dropsite minting Contract:

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
import "./ERC1155_Dropsite.sol"; 
contract Dropsite is ERC1155_Dropsite  { 

    //NFT category
    bytes  data ="";

    uint TotalNFTsMinted;     //Total NFTs
    uint numOfCopies;         //A user can mint only 1 NFT
    //Initial Minting
    uint Diamond;            
    uint Gold;
    uint Silver;

    //owner-NFT-ID Mapping
    mapping (address=>uint)  dropsite_NFT_Owner;
    //payments Mapping
     mapping (address => uint) deposits;
  modifier OnlyOwner {
        require(_msgSender() == Owner, "Only NFT-ES Owner can Access");
        _;
    }

    //Pausing and activating the contract
    modifier contractIsNotPaused(){
        require (IsPaused == false, "Dropsite is not Opened Yet." );
        _;
    }
      bool public IsPaused = true;
    address payable public  Owner;
    string private _name;
    
    constructor (string memory name){
        _name = name;
        Owner = payable(msg.sender);

        TotalNFTsMinted=0;     //Total NFTs Minted
        numOfCopies=1;         //A user can mint only 1 NFT
        Diamond=0;            
        Gold=0;
        Silver=0;
    }
     
     function checkMintedCategoryWise() public view OnlyOwner returns(uint,uint,uint){
         return (Diamond,Gold,Silver);
     }
    function checkTotalMinted() public view OnlyOwner returns(uint){
         return TotalNFTsMinted;
     }
     function stopDropsite() public OnlyOwner{
        require(IsPaused==false, "Dropsite is already Stopped");
        IsPaused=true;
    }

     function openDropsite() public OnlyOwner {
        require(IsPaused==true, "Dropsite is already Running");
        IsPaused=false;
    }
    
     //To WithDraw All Ammount from Contract to Owners Address 
    function withDraw(address payable to) public payable OnlyOwner {
        uint Balance = address(this).balance;
        require(Balance > 0 wei, "Error! No Balance to withdraw"); 
        to.transfer(Balance);
    }  
    
    //To Check Contract Balance in Wei
      function ContractBalance() public view OnlyOwner returns (uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function random() internal view returns (uint) {
        //Only Returns 0,1,2
    uint randomnumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))) % 3;
    return randomnumber;
    }

   function updateConditions(uint nftId) internal contractIsNotPaused {
           // if nftID is 0, and less than 51 so 50 MAX
           
    if(nftId == 0 && Diamond < 50) {
        data = "Diamond";
        Diamond++; 

    // if nftID is 0 or 1 and Diamond is more than 150, it will go there
    } else if(nftId <= 1 && Gold < 100) {
        data = "Gold";
        Gold++;

    // if any of the above conditions are filled it will mint silver if enough silver available
    } else if(nftId <= 2 && Silver <= 850) {
        data="Silver";
        Silver++;
    }
    else 
    revert("Some Error Occured");     
   }
    //Random minting after Fiat Payments
    function FiatrandomMint(address user_addr) OnlyOwner contractIsNotPaused public returns (uint,string memory) {
     require(TotalNFTsMinted<1000, "Max Minting Limit reached");
   uint nftId = random(); // we're assuming that random() returns only 0,1,2    
    updateConditions(nftId);
    _mint(user_addr, nftId, numOfCopies, data);
    TotalNFTsMinted++;
    dropsite_NFT_Owner[user_addr]=nftId;
    return (nftId,string(data));
    }
    
    function depositAmount(address payee,uint amountToDeposit) internal {
        deposits[payee] += amountToDeposit;
    }
    //Random minting after Crypto Payments
    function CryptoRandomMint(address user_addr)  contractIsNotPaused public payable returns (uint,string memory) {
     require(TotalNFTsMinted<1000, "Max Minting Limit reached");
     require(msg.value == (25), "Balance must be 25 Matics");
   uint nftId = random(); // we're assuming that random() returns only 0,1,2
     updateConditions(nftId);
    _mint(user_addr, nftId, numOfCopies, data);
    depositAmount(_msgSender(), msg.value);
    TotalNFTsMinted++;
    dropsite_NFT_Owner[user_addr]=nftId;
    return (nftId,string(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: @Kerry99 Updated!

Answer (score 0):

If I figured your question right. You want for a `Marketplace contract` to get ownership of `Distributed NFTs`.

To do that, you would usually use `transferOwnership()` function. You can find an example of it in OpenZeppelin library. There is even a contract Ownabale.sol written for that specific purpose. (Though it deals with ownership of contracts)

It seems like you had written your own Ownership logic in your case. I would advise using `OpenZeppelin` instead, I am positive they have a solution for this, likey even inside the ERC1155 standard. Even more so, as their code is audited, there is far less chance of introducing security exploits.

Comment: Yes, You figured out right.
OpenZeppelin Ownable library works only for contracts. But I want to only have record(Or any other solution) of Minted NFTs from Dropsite Contract to Marketplace contract. So that my users may sell them on Marketplace.
In my marketplace contract I have used OpenZeppelin contracts and its completely secure. But for dropsite the custom logic is my requirement. It is simple minting on an address using Openzeppelin _mint() function.
What I want now is some way to sell that minted NFT from Dropsite on my marketplace.